# Install Linux and Android in a x86_64 device with preinstalled android

Tags: arch-linux, android

I have a tablet with a x86-64 intel processor, which is a Chuwi Hi12. This tablet can boot an USB device, so I can boot Linux (ArchLinux) in this tablet. Also, I can install Linux in this device without problems, but removing Android. Android version is 5.1. This tablet comes with Android and Windows.

There is only one way to (re)install android on it. You have to flash de GPT and Android from a PC using `Intel Phone Flash Tool`. The loaded GPT includes these partitions (output of fdisk -l):

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 58.2 GiB, 62537072640 bytes, 122142720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Device             Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1    206848   411647   204800  100M EFI System
/dev/mmcblk0p2      2048   206847   204800  100M Microsoft basic data
/dev/mmcblk0p3    411648   473087    61440   30M unknown
/dev/mmcblk0p4    473088   534527    61440   30M unknown
/dev/mmcblk0p5    534528   536575     2048    1M unknown
/dev/mmcblk0p6    536576   569343    32768   16M unknown
/dev/mmcblk0p7    569344  5812223  5242880  2.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk0p8   5812224  6336511   524288  256M Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk0p9   6336512 27308031 20971520   10G Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk0p10 27308032 27310079     2048    1M Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk0p11 27310080 27326463    16384    8M Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/mmcblk0boot1: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mmcblk0boot0: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 14.9 GiB, 16008609792 bytes, 31266816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x610aca7c

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        0 1128447 1128448  551M  0 Empty
/dev/sda2         164  131235  131072   64M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


Disk /dev/loop0: 442.1 MiB, 463548416 bytes, 905368 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Main storage device is mmcblk0. As you can see, Android only takes around 13 GiB of the device, but it has about 58 GiB of storage.

Because of this is the only way to install android to this tablet (with drivers), I have to install first android, and after that, I would like to install Linux (using the 45 GiB free memory). I created new partitions (using fdisk) after Android partitions, and I installed Linux on this partition, but I can not configure GRUB to recognize android and Linux, so my question is: How to make GRUB to recognize both Android and Linux (Arch Linux, x86_64-efi)?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Android/Linux dualboot both on a Chuwi Hi10 and a Chuwi Hi12. AFAICT, they are identical regarding the boot process, so the instructions detailed here for the Hi10 should work for you, too: https://github.com/floe/tuxblet#linuxandroid-dual-boot

TLDR: after Linux installation, on the EFI partition, do the following:

- `cp /loader.efi /EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`
- `mkdir /EFI/Microsoft/`
- `cp -a /EFI/ubuntu/ /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/`
- `cp /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/shimx64.efi /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`

Afterwards, you can use the Windows entry in the firmware boot menu to boot Linux instead.